# POST throwing undefined index on every var

Tags: php, post, echo

I'm defining POST here:

```
else if(isset($_POST["Edit"])){
    $result_set = $sqlConn->query("SELECT Art, Ime, Cijena, Kol FROM permatable WHERE Art='{$_POST["Art"]}' LIMIT 1");
    $Item = $result_set->fetch_array();
    $_POST["Art"] = $Item["Art"];
    $_POST["Ime"] = $Item["Ime"];
    $_POST["Cijena"] = $Item["Cijena"];
    $_POST["Kol"] = $Item["Kol"];   
    header("Location: EditP.php");
}
```

Now the Post "Edit" and the if statment is being called just fine. I've also checked the query and it returns everything it needs to. 
Now on the header location I get undefined index on all of these vars and thats coming from the following code:

```
echo "<input type='text' placeholder=".$_POST["Art"]." name='Art'>
    <input type='text' placeholder=".$_POST["Ime"]. "name='Ime'>
    <input type='text' placeholder=".$_POST["Cijena"]." name='Cijena'>
    <input type='text' placeholder=".$_POST["Kol"]." name='Kol'>";
```

Am I doing something wrong? I can't see any mistakes myself and this has been bothering me for a while now.

Comment: You're trying to set up POST before sending to another file? That won't work. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use cURL?

Comment: Why don't you just do something like: `else if (isset($_POST["Edit"])) { include('EditP.php'); }`

Comment: Yes, you're doing several things wrong. First thing, unrelated to your initial problem is that you are open to SQL injection. Second thing is that you always assume the database will return something. Third thing is that you are changing locations, or if you will - actual PHP scripts that are being executed. The variables aren't preserved from script to script in the `$_POST`. It's the `$_SESSION` you're after.

Comment: You need to use sessions. You can't populate post, and expect to get the stuff in another file after a redirect. $_POST won't contain anything when their browser hits EditP.php. Use $_SESSION.

Comment: @N.B. SQL Injection and other exploits are not a problem as this is only gonna be a local app for a very specific user, database will always return something cause we are getting to "Edit" POST by clicking on a database item. I'm looking to just load POST with vars so I can put them in a placeholder. I didn't know it wasn't possible, I'll just use SESSION instead

Comment: @user2979816 - if someone stumbles upon your question, it's good to know that the code you're using is not something that should be used. Process of making the code safer consists of 2-3 lines of code extra, it's not a big deal. Also, you should *never* assume that people who exploit things are people with bad intentions. At some point, your client will type in an illegal character and will get an error on the screen. At that point, you'll be getting a phone call that something isn't working. Whether you fix it now or in 3 months when project grows, totally up to you, I'm just mentioning it.

Comment: @N.B. well, you're right about that, I'll add it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I used SESSION at the end so I just changed the code to following:

```
$result_set = $sqlConn->query("SELECT Art, Ime, Cijena, Kol FROM permatable WHERE Art='{$_POST["Art"]}' LIMIT 1");
    $Item = $result_set->fetch_array();
    $_SESSION["Art"] = $Item["Art"];
    $_SESSION["Ime"] = $Item["Ime"];
    $_SESSION["Cijena"] = $Item["Cijena"];
    $_SESSION["Kol"] = $Item["Kol"];    
    header("Location: EditP.php");
```

And for the EditP:

```
echo "<input type='text' placeholder=".$_SESSION["Art"]." name='Art'>
<input type='text' placeholder=".$_SESSION["Ime"]. "name='Ime'>
<input type='text' placeholder=".$_SESSION["Cijena"]." name='Cijena'>
<input type='text' placeholder=".$_SESSION["Kol"]." name='Kol'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

That won't work.

you can't send POST with header location

you can try to add them to your url

```
    foreach($item as $key=>$value)
    {
      $items .= $key."&".$value ;
    }
header("Location: EditP.php?".$items);
```

and in the edit.php page

```
echo "<input type='text' placeholder=".$_GET["Art"]." name='Art'>
    <input type='text' placeholder=".$_GET["Ime"]. "name='Ime'>
    <input type='text' placeholder=".$_GET["Cijena"]." name='Cijena'>
    <input type='text' placeholder=".$_GET["Kol"]." name='Kol'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot redirect the user w/ POST variables. It will not work. [Read here](http://thisinterestsme.com/php-redirecting-a-form-with-post-variables/). The best way to do it is to create a form and then automatically submit it via JavaScript as soon as the page loads. Example:

```
<form id="my_form" action="http://example.com" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($email); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="etc" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($etc); ?>">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //Our form submission function.
    function submitForm() {
        document.getElementById('my_form').submit();
    }
    //Call the function submitForm() as soon as the page has loaded.
    window.onload = submitForm;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result_set = $sqlConn->query("SELECT Art, Ime, Cijena, Kol FROM permatable WHERE Art='($_POST["Art"])' LIMIT 1");
```

Try changing curly braces to small braces.